# TYPO3 7.6.30 - Problems with creating a new user

Tags: typo3, admin, backend, typo3-7.6.x

I got this TYPO3 7.6.30 running. Creating a new user (or admin) works but he cannot login although there is a crypted password in the database. 
If I change it directly in the database the login works. If the user changes it in his backend, the login works. If I change it again in the backend, it doesn't work anymore.

The loginSecurityLevel is set to RSA for Backend and Frontend. Setting the loginSecurityLevel to normal didn't help. Passwords like "a" neither. Errorlog says "Password not accepted".

I am slowly running out of ideas...last straw: debugging the core where the password is set. ^^

If you got any idea be my guest. Thx!

TZP

Update:
Ok, I found the problem but I don't know why it's going wrong. Turns out that the PHP crypt function creates something totally weird.

```
crypt('myUncryptedPW', 'myPWAsHash') == 'myPWAsHash';
```

and if that's true everything is fine. Next step: trying to understand PHP crypt. ^^

Comment: Ok, I found the problem but I don't know why it's going wrong. Turns out that the PHP crypt function creates something totally weird. 

crypt('myUncryptedPW', 'myPWAsHash') == 'myPWAsHash';

and if that's true everything is fine. Next step: trying to understand PHP crypt. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution...not the best but it works. Turns out that without the "rsaAuth"-extension everything works like a charm. I m not sure why this causes so much trouble but that should do the trick until we use TYPO3 9. ^^